# math theory- primes problem

Tags: prime-numbers

[image]

I have tried to prove it for over $15$ hours with no success. 
I got a clue to use the following technique: between $((P_n), \:2(P_n))$ there is an additional prime hiding there - $P_{n+1}$.

please only clues and no  solutions!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the hint you got, you know that $p_{n+3} \le 2 p_{n+2} \le 2 (2p_{n+1})$. 
Thus $p_{n+3}^2 \le 8 p_{n+1}p_{n+2} < p_n p_{n+1}p_{n+2}$ for all $n$ such that $p_n > 8$. That is $n \ge 5$.

You can check by hand it also holds for $n=3$ and $n=4$.

Comment: quid, perfect :)

Comment: Thanks. Not sure it is perfect though. Maybe one should avoid the special casing.

Comment: I asked for a clue.. anyway thanks this solution is very nice.

Comment: @StavAlfi yes, sorry, I did not really register this. Else I might have left out a detail here or there.